# How to understand the requirements for IFR currency?

Tags: faa-regulations, instrument-flight-rules

So the requirement reads "six instrument approaches;
Holding procedures; and
Intercepting and tracking courses through the use of navigation systems."

I am still a little unclear on how to interpret that statement. I have been told you need to have a combination of the above that equal 6, but you could also read that as you need 6 approaches, 6 holds, 6 Intercepting and Tracking through Navigation Systems. Can someone help explain what I am missing from that rule?

Answer (score 5):

The regulation here seems to be 14 CFR 61.57(c)(1). The way that the regulation is written, we can see that there are three separate requirements:

> (1) Use of an airplane, powered-lift, helicopter, or airship for maintaining instrument experience. Within the 6 calendar months preceding the month of the flight, that person performed and logged at least the following tasks and iterations in an airplane, powered-lift, helicopter, or airship, as appropriate, for the instrument rating privileges to be maintained in actual weather conditions, or under simulated conditions using a view-limiting device that involves having performed the following -
>
> (i) Six instrument approaches.
>
> (ii) Holding procedures and tasks.
>
> (iii) Intercepting and tracking courses through the use of navigational electronic systems.

So it's not "a combination of the above that total 6", and it's not 6 of each. It's 6 of the first one, and any amount of both of the other two.